# Is there a way to make this more succinct or more readable?

Tags: swift

I'm interested in the last few lines of code at the bottom -- not looking for a critique of the classes.  Those are just there so you have some code to experiment with.  Is there a way to put that all together?  Seems like the long way around but can't figure out how to make it better.  I don't really need the intermittent batch of allobjects, just the sorted one.

```
import Foundation

class AnItem: NSObject {
    var theString: String = ""
}

class GroupOfItems: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var lotsOfItems = NSSet()

    init(withTitle: String, andInitialValue value: String) {
        super.init()
        title = withTitle
        addNewItemToList(withValue: value)
    }

    func addNewItemToList(withValue value: String) -> Int {
        let freshItem = AnItem()
        freshItem.theString = value
        lotsOfItems = lotsOfItems.adding(freshItem) as NSSet
        return lotsOfItems.count
    }
}

var myGroup = GroupOfItems(withTitle: "My title", andInitialValue: "First item")
myGroup.addNewItemToList(withValue: "Second item")
myGroup.addNewItemToList(withValue: "Third item")

var anArrayOfItems = myGroup.lotsOfItems.allObjects as! [AnItem]
anArrayOfItems = anArrayOfItems.sorted(by: { (s1: AnItem, s2: AnItem) -> Bool in
    return s1.theString < s2.theString
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSSet`? Why not a Swift set? And why extend `NSObject`? Yes, I know you said to ignore the classes but those details matter.

Comment: `anArrayOfItems = anArrayOfItems.sorted() { $0.theString < $1.theString }`

Comment: This is actually regarding an NSFetchedResultsController implementation I'm working on.  I have a to-many relationship in the model and it returns an NSSet.  I made this playground to try to understand how to work with it.  I'm new to Swift and haven't coded in a long time.  The NSObject is there because it made the playground quit complaining.  Was in a hurry to work on my problem.

Comment: @vacawama: Yep.  That does make it cleaner.  I should've seen that one.  But I'd still like to find a way to eliminate the intermediate step.  I don't need the allobjects result for anything other than casting the [Any] to [AnItem].  Is there no way to do it all at once?

Comment: You can do it in one line, but I'm unclear if that is what you are looking for: `let anArrayOfItems = (myGroup.lotsOfItems.allObjects as! [AnItem]).sorted() { $0.theString < $1.theString }`

Comment: @vacawama: That was exactly what I was looking for.  Ouch.  Sometimes we noobs get so caught up with the intricate details of the language that the simple act of enclosing something in parentheses totally slips our mind!  Thank you.